# dynamically show selected value in select list dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor, drop-down-menu

I created a Cascading of Dropdown list for Country state city in my application using Ajax request and Select Box.
My application gathers information about users ie personal info etc.
In my application there is an option to Edit the entered fields.. upon clicking the edit button the personal information page is populated with previously entered data.
Now i need help to show the selected value that is which country, state and city is selected by the user in my select box dropdown.
Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store the old values for each select box and resume it after loading values from ajax like

```
var old_val = $('#state').val();
$('#state').html('<here option string from ajax>');
$('#state').val(old_val);
```

now when you show the dropdown for edit you can get the selected values from database and generate one option tag for all three dropdowns

once loaded you can trigger chain of ajax for the same and values will not lost